# WordPress Permalink structure mysite.com/blog/%postname%/%post_id%/

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

On my site Im using: mysite.com/blog/%postname%/%post_id%/ as Permalink structure.

So I have 1 post at: mysite.com/blog/my-first-post/1234/

But this same post is also possible to visit at: (without postID)
mysite.com/blog/my-first-post/

Will that cause double contents issue? Why or how is it possible to visit this same post with 2 different URLS? I don't understand why WordPress do this. Im using WordPress 3.6.1

Answer (score 2):

What does it show in Wordpress/Site? If all links on your site point to `mysite.com/blog/my-first-post/1234` Google will visit that link and not your `mysite.com/blog/my-first-post`. As far as I know, Google will not be aware of that link.

But if in your post/wordpress you manually link to your post/page as `mysite.com/blog/my-first-post` then, Google will visit it and maybe mark it as duplicate content.

Even on StackOverflow, the url `stackoverflow.com/questions/19253513/wordpress-permalink-structure-mysite-com-blog-postname-post-id` will be the same as `stackoverflow.com/questions/19253513` , but on every link there is on stackoverflow to that page, the URL will be the former. Google doesn't know about the latter link.

Comment: Visiting stackoverflow.com/questions/19253513 auto redirects to stackoverflow.com/questions/19253513/wordpress-permalink-structure-mysite-com-blog-postname-post-id I guess you are right about Google is not aware of the link without postID. I have not made any manual link so my sitemap.xml and Site shows all links with postID.